# Keras fit_generator issue

Tags: python, keras, generator

I followed [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to create a custom generator for my Keras model. Here is an MWE that shows the issues I'm facing:

```
import sys, keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, batch_size, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        #print('self.batch_size: ', self.batch_size)
        print('index: ', index)
        sys.exit()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        print('self.indexes: ', self.indexes)
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)

        X1 = np.empty((self.batch_size, 10), dtype=float)
        X2 = np.empty((self.batch_size, 12),  dtype=int)

        #Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            print('i is: ', i, 'ID is: ', ID)

            #Preprocess this sample (omitted)
            X1[i,] = np.repeat(1, X1.shape[1])
            X2[i,] = np.repeat(2, X2.shape[1])

        Y = X1[:,:-1]
        return X1, X2, Y

if __name__=='__main__':
    train_ids_to_use = list(np.arange(1, 321)) #1, 2, ...,320 
    valid_ids_to_use = list(np.arange(321, 481)) #321, 322, ..., 480

    params = {'batch_size': 32}

    train_generator = DataGenerator(train_ids_to_use, **params)
    valid_generator = DataGenerator(valid_ids_to_use, **params)

    #Build a toy model
    input_1 = Input(shape=(3, 10))
    input_2 = Input(shape=(3, 12))
    y_input = Input(shape=(3, 10))

    concat_1 = keras.layers.concatenate([input_1, input_2])
    concat_2 = keras.layers.concatenate([concat_1, y_input])

    dense_1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(concat_2)
    output_1 = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)

    model = Model([input_1, input_2, y_input], output_1)
    print(model.summary())

    #Compile and fit_generator
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss=binary_crossentropy)
    model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, validation_data = valid_generator, epochs=2, verbose=2)
```

I don't want to shuffle my input data. I thought that was getting handled, but in my code, when I print out `index` in `__get_item__`, I get random numbers. I would like consecutive numbers. Notice I'm trying to kill the process using `sys.exit` inside `__getitem__` to see what's going on.

My questions:

1. Why does `index` not go consecutively? How can I fix this?
2. When I run this in the terminal using screen, why doesn't it respond to Ctrl+C?

Comment: I think you can achieve that by passing `shuffle=False` to `fit_generator` method?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did that as a default in the `__init__`, and I tested later whether the index values were getting shuffled by the if statement in `on_epoch_end`. I found that things in the if statement did not get executed, which I think means that shuffle is indeed false.

Comment: You want the batch indices to be generated consecutively, right? So that's what `shuffle=False` argument of `fit_generator` is. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, please see the above comment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. On my machine, when I set `shuffle=False` in `fit_generator` call (not in the `__init__` method), I would get consecutive indices.

Comment: Hmm. I tried passing another named parameter, using your idea: 
params = {'batch_size': 32, 'shuffle'=False} and I still get non-consecutive indices.

Comment: I am talking about `fit_generator`... the last line in your code above. Forget about your custom generator for a moment and pass `shuffle=False` to `fit_generator` method and see what the result is.

Comment: Thank you! Why is that? I thought I was overriding the default fit_generator by writing my own custom one...is that not the case?

Comment: `fit_generator` is not a generator. It is a method for fitting the model using the generators which you pass to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `shuffle` argument of `fit_generator` method to generate batches consecutively. From `fit_generator()` [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator):

> **shuffle:** Boolean. Whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the beginning of each epoch. Only used with instances of `Sequence` (`keras.utils.Sequence`). Has no effect when `steps_per_epoch` is not `None`.

Just pass `shuffle=False` to `fit_generator`:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, shuffle=False, ...)
```

Comment: Okay, please let me check my understanding: `fit_generator` is not being overridden, it belongs to Keras and has its own parameters. What I'm doing with `DataGenerator` is creating my own generators (train_generator and valid_generator) to create slices of the data for Keras to use. But why does that mean I need to specify `shuffle=False` in the call to `fit_generator`, instead of in my own generators?

Comment: @StatsSorceress `fit_generator` has been implemented such that it would call the `__getitem__` method of the `Sequence` with a given index value. So it is the `fit_generator` which gives you the index of the batch to be generated. Passing `shuffle=False` to `fit_generator` forces it give batch indices in order, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...